# Python MySQLdb execute table variable

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to use a variable for a table name. I get the error "... near ''myTable'' at line 1
I must not be escaping this right. The double '' in the error seems to be a clue, but I don't get it.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pw","database" )
table = "myTable"
def geno_order(db, table):
    cursor = db.cursor() # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    sql = "SELECT * FROM %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, table)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I am sure there are several duplicates. I picked the one I knew, but if someone else finds one that is even more like the OP's problem by all means use it instead.

Answer (score 18):

You can't use a parameter for the table name in the `execute` call. You'll need to use normal Python string interpolation for that:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM %s" % table
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Naturally, you'll need to be extra careful if the table name is coming from user input. To mitigate SQL injection, validate the table name against a list of valid names.

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {0}(var_name)VALUES({1});".format('table_name','"value"'))  #if you need to insert more variables