# Python MySQLdb - Programming Around SQL Injection Code

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, code-injection, mysql-python

First, i'm very new to stack overflow (first question posted) and forums in general.
In addition to this downfall, I'm also new to development and databases other than at a Systems Administration type level.

I see several questions about using variables in Python with the MySQLdb module on stackoverflow. Many of them have mention of SQL Injection code like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables) The answer with 70 + upvotes gives you an example where % appears to be the deciding character in whether or not your code is susceptible to SQL Injection. My questions are:

1. Do I understand correctly that the "" % (VAR) instead of "", (VAR) is what makes the difference ?
2. If that is the case, then is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255694/python-mysqldb-execute-table-variable) also an example or is there something different with using the % to designate a table vs a clause ?

It is noteworthy to mention I've tried learning more about SQL Injection. Not sure if I'm too dense or the material is but i'm just not following. In this [article by cisco](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html) I tried to follow, I find that there is no mention of a percent but instead they appear to be using ?. So if someone can point me to some "layman's" documentation I would appreciate that!

Comment: SQL injection becomes possible as soon as you start integrating user input into your queries. This is [one of the most famous illustrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). [This reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1446005), although initially appying to PHP, also provide tons of valuable information on how to prevent this, regardless of the language.

Comment: Check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1973/1446005) too.

Comment: @RandomSeed thanks for the quick response. I will review your links but I believe that was the missing piece. With all of the reading I did, I failed to realize that it was user input. I've basically worried about the wrong thing since mine isn't based on user input. However, now that I know more about it, i'm very interested.

Comment: Sufficient time has now passed for you to add your self-answer as an actual answer. Please do so, using [the revision history of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18028576/revisions) if necessary to retrieve the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomSeed posted the correct answer to my question so I'll repost:

SQL injection becomes possible as soon as you start integrating user input into your queries. This is one of the [most famous illustrations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) [This reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), although initially appying to PHP, also provide tons of valuable information on how to prevent this, regardless of the language

Comment: Please include the link in your answer.