# Python mySQLdb posting data to a dynamic table

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm attempting to post data to a table where the name of the table is a variable, i receive no errors, however no data is posting.

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' %data[1])

0L

sql ="""CREATE TABLE %s  (IP TEXT, AVAILIBILITY INT)""" %data[1]
cursor.execute(sql)
0L

for key in data[0]:
    print type(key), type(data[0][key])
    sql = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s)""" %(data[1],key,data[0][key])
```

Comment: Related and probably a duplicate: [Python MySQLdb execute table variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255694/python-mysqldb-execute-table-variable).

Comment: do you `db.commit()`?

Comment: You're right, i wasn't using db.commit() That made the runtime take longer and i thought it would work but it's still not posting

Answer (score 0):

Your code never executes the `INSERT` statement; it only defines a string `sql`. You'll need to add a `cursor.execute` call inside the loop.

You should also be parameterizing your query as much as possible, even when you can't parameterize some part (like a table or column name). I recommend using [advanced string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) here to avoid having to escape your parameterization placeholders.

If you had written it this way to begin with, you might have noticed the missing line more easily:

```
for key in data[0]:
    sql = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s,%s)'.format(data[1])  # can't supply object names
    cursor.execute(sql, (key, data[0][key]))               # as parameters, but values ok
```