# querying mysql database in python where table is a variable

Tags: python, mysql

I am aware this may be a duplicate post. However I have looked at the other posts and cant figure it out in my case.

```
from configdata import configdata

from dbfiles.dbconnect import connection 

c,conn = connection()

table = configdata()[4]
userid = 'jdeepee'

value = c.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE userid = (%s)" % (table), userid)

print(value)
```

I think the code is self explanatory. But essentially what I am trying to do is query a MySQL database based on a variable for the integer and userid. I believe my syntax is wrong not sure how to fix it however. Help would be great.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255694/python-mysqldb-execute-table-variable

Comment: I have tried to do that, I think it is the user id causing some issues. I get the error: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: I am curious. Why would you have code which reads a row from any table? If table is unknown in some part of code, the resulting row data will also contain unknown columns. How do you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value = c.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE userid = %s".format(table), (userid,))
```

Basically, you need to interpolate the table name into the query first, then pass any query parameters to `.execute()` in a tuple.