# Python MySQLdb Syntax Error with seemingly correct syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to do a simple retrieval of a column named N_NUMBER in a MySQL table using the following code:

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import MySQLdb    

TABLE_NAME = 'testmaster'

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path) # loads the .env

dbName = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=os.environ.get('DB_HOST'), user=os.environ.get('DB_USER'), passwd=os.environ.get('DB_PASS'), db=dbName)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT N_NUMBER FROM %s", (TABLE_NAME,))
```

I continue to get the same Traceback every time, which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updateMaster.py", line 101, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT 'N_NUMBER' FROM %s", (TABLE_NAME,))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''testmaster'' at line 1")
```

I've also tried the syntax with pyformat style as recommended by the docs for the .execute() method, but still received the same error. The pyformat style looked like:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT N_NUMBER FROM %(table_name)s", {'table_name':TABLE_NAME})
```

When I try directly inserting the table name into the command string, the command works, leading me to suspect that it has something to do with the %s. What's going wrong?

Comment: You cannot parameterize a table name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255694/python-mysqldb-execute-table-variable (same goes for column names as well).

Comment: Thank you! I knew this question was probably asked somewhere but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parametrize table nor column names. While being cognisant of the possibility of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, instead do:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT N_NUMBER FROM {}".format(TABLE_NAME))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you :)

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.